# Copy last column values

Tags: powershell

I have a text file (dynamically generated by another script) as shown below:

```
host1       A      Answer     myip1
host6557    A      Answer     myip2
host12      A      Question   myip3
host253     A      Answer     myip4
```

What I want: I need to copy "myip" columns from this file. As you can see the space between "host" and "A" is not fixed. For ex, between host1 and A has 7 spaces, but between host6557 and A has just 4 spaces. I need to just copy the last column which all will start with some values, say "10." or "192."

How can this be achieved in PowerShell?

**Update**

1. I want this data to be pasted in another file in place of 1st column where the contents will be as shown below: Which means I need to replace values of ip1,2,3 with these copied values.

   [image]
2. If it's done, suppose let's say I have 4th value like above (without credentials) I again need to copy the username, password from 3rd value and paste it there near to 4th value. Final expected figure:

   [image]

**Update**

```psh
$hip = Get-Content "C:\timezone\host - Copy.txt"
foreach ($ips in $hip) {
  $ip = $ips -split ','
  $sip = $ip[0]

  if ($iplist -match $sip) {
    Write-Host "Nothing to do"
  } else {
    Add-Content $hip "`n$iplist',username,password'"
  }
}
```

No error, but I cant find it checks the last if loop, because for all values it says "nothing to do".

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-split` operator to split the line at consecutive spaces, and take the last element:

```
Get-Content testfile.txt |
foreach { ($_.trim() -split '\s+')[-1] }
```

The `.trim()` will remove any potential trailing spaces in the line that would result in the last split element being a null.

Comment: Thanks. But can you please see my update 1 and 2 on the post.?

Comment: @serverstackqns Please show some effort. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: Hey @AnsgarWiechers: Please dont comment as if you're my boss.. Just come here if you want to know how much I am putting effort. I am trying with my own way, but things are not working and I am here.. It's not that I am asking questions for fun. Understand and speak!!!!

Comment: @serverstackqns What you're doing is called "scope creep" (adding more conditions to the question after it's already posted and you've gotten answers).  You've compounded it by failing to post any code that would tell us how you've tried to solve it so that we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Obviously it's finding a match somewhere in that list of ip addresses.  You'd need to see to data to figure out where it's finding that match and you're the only one that's got the data.  If you want answers, you need to learn to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is much easier to acheive, if you let powershell do the dirty parsing work for you.

Given that the multiple-spaces-separated file from your question is `hosts.txt` and the comma-separated-file `credentials.txt`, you can use the following approach to turn them into collections of powershell objects, that you can work with:

```
$hosts = ConvertFrom-Csv (gc .\hosts.txt | % { $_ -replace '\s+', ',' }) -Header 'Computername','Foo','Bar','IP'
$credentials = Import-Csv -Path .\credentials.txt -Header 'IP', 'Username','Password'
```

To substitute the ip column, you may try something along this lines:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $credentials.Length; $i++)
{ 
    $credentials[$i].IP = $hosts[$i].IP
}
```

I get from your question that you might have more hosts, than credentials to correlate them to and that for the remaining hosts you want the credentials from previous lines copied over. I would do something like this:

```
$remainingHosts = @()
if ($hosts.Length -gt $credentials.Length)
{
    $remainingHosts = $hosts[($credentials.Length)..($hosts.Length-1)]
}

$lastCredentials = $credentials[-1]
foreach ($h in $remainingHosts)
{
    $credentials += $lastCredentials | select -Property @{Name='IP'; Expression={$h.IP}},Username,Password
}
```

Finally to save the result back to your `credentials.txt` you can again take the csv approach:

```
$null, $credentialCsv = $credentials | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
$credentialCsv | Out-File .\credentials.txt
```

Of course instead of hacking back and forth between csv and "something similar to csv" you may consider using proper csv-files.